# How can I read Excel files with symfony2?

Tags: symfony, phpexcel

I installed `Excelbundle` with `PhpExcel` library. I want to read excel files I found this function.

How can I use it? Any suggestion?

```
public function xlsAction()
{
    $filenames = "your-file-name";
    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($filenames);

    foreach ($phpExcelObject ->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle();
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex();
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                if (!is_null($cell)) {
                    echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ' , $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please precise you question. What's you problem?

Comment: I don't know how to use the bundle to read excel file

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is "Read the documentation" and start hacking at it. Working with excel is, in my experience, quite complex and time consuming so don't expect other people to solve your problem online.

It seems like you're talking about this bundle:
https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

It has great documentation, even full examples (see "Fake Controller").

Answer (score 0):

With PHPExcel it is quite easy to read a Excel document.

See my example :

```
$dir       = $this->getContainer()->getParameter("kernel.root_dir") . "/../../data/import/";
$file_name = "my_excel_file.xlsx";
$excel = $this->getContainer()->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name);
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();

$row = 0;
 while ($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue()) {

    $data = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue(); // get value from nth line and 2nf column

    //do stuff -- see doc for functions on $sheet

 }
```